# Exclude objects from Wordpress API based from ACF field using rest_prepare_{$post_type}

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, api, rest-api

Lets say i only want custom posts where (date('Y-m-d H:i:s')<{acf_date_field})
I tried to return null; from my_rest_prepare_post. It seems like its working, but is this good practice, or should i do this another way?

After some more testing i see im left with null objects in my response and that is not optimal.

```
function my_rest_prepare_post($data, $post, $request) 
{
    $_data = $data->data;

    $fields = get_fields($post->ID);

    foreach ($fields as $key => $value){

        if ($key == 'sk_pameldte_rep'){
            continue;
        }

        if ($key == "sk_dato_og_klokkeslett"){
            $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            if($today<$value){
                return null;
            }
        }

        $_data[$key] = get_field($key, $post->ID);

    }

    $data->data = $_data;

    //unset( $data->data['id'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['date_gmt'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['guid'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['modified_gmt'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['featured_media'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['parent'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['template'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['_links'] ); 
    unset( $data->data['template'] ); 

    return $data;

}
```

Thank you guys

Solved thanks to @mmm

Added this and removed the date functionality from my_rest_prepare_post:

```
function my_rest_query($args){

$args['meta_key'] ='sk_dato_og_klokkeslett';
$args['meta_value'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$args['meta_compare'] ='>';


return $args;
}
```

Comment: you can filter the result to clean NULL values with the filter `rest_request_after_callbacks`. another solution is to use the filter `"rest_{$this->post_type}_query"` which defines the query arguments. look here to use it to filter by meta value : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Thank you @mmm . Worked like a charm. I Used rest_{$this->post_type}_query